# Cannot connect to local IRC server

Tags: irc

I have been working on to create a local IRC server. The problem is i cannot connect to the IRC server from a different machine, although i can access it from the local host from the server.

When it try to use it from another machine (I use mIRC, typed /server [IP] ), it always says "Unable to connect to server"

What am I missing here? I am using UnrealIRC 3.2.10.6 on CentOS 7

Here is the pastebin of the unrealircd.conf file http://pastebin.com/Uuj81ija

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your firewall via `iptables -L` or `systemctl status firewalld`. Do `netstat -tulpn` to see if UnrealIRCd is binding to the correct IP address. Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to see if SELinux is enabled and denying the port bind.

These are basic troubleshooting techniques that you can use whenever something's not connecting correctly.